# Codeigniter photo upload and use

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have made a photo upload function, it cannot be uploaded to the uploads folder in the root`$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')` always does not work because it always goes to Material_view page.

viewer:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart ('index.php/Main/do_upload'); ?>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('title'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td><?php echo form_upload('userfile'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></td>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </tr>       
</table>
```

Controller

```
public function do_upload()
    {
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('Material_view', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
    }
```

And can I ask that after I upload the photo, how can I use it in viewer?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Try to use codeigniter upload library to upload file or image.

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: I know codeiginiter has a helper, but is there any problem with these code? And could you please tell me how to use photo in view after upload?

Comment: You should change `form_open()` to `form_open_multipart()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my answer based on your new code:

you are calling an incorrect field (as you didn't modify the tutorial's example to suit your custom view.

Controller:

```
public function do_upload()
{
        $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']             = 100;
        $config['max_width']            = 1024;
        $config['max_height']           = 768;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('pic'))
        {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                $this->load->view('Material_view', $error);
        }
        else
        {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I have modified the code, but it still doesn't work. There is no picture in my uploads file and the function seems never work because it always go to Material_view page

Comment: Are you getting any errors from the errorlog? permission denied, destination folder doesnt exist?

Comment: in your controller $this->upload->do_upload('userfile') is incorrect, you need to use the field name you have in your view which would mean using: $this->upload->do_upload('pic')

Comment: Yea, sry the viewer is an old one, I have modified it. Still doesn't work, no error just no picture in my folder and the $this->upload->do_upload('userfile') never work because the page always goer to Material_view page

Comment: You are going to Material_view page because of the IF statement sending it there: if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')), this means if $this->upload->do_upload('userfile') is not set then display the Material_view. I suggest starting again with the full tutorial code and building from there, the tutorial code works. besides that other issues might be invalid write permissions to the upload folder...